# Column sorting in jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have gone through the column sorting in jQuery datatable plugin and the various ways of controlling it.. I have a query is it possible to control sorting in such a way that clicking on upper arrow icon will do sorting in ascending order &  down arrow icon will do sorting in descending order??

Comment: Can you tell me is both arrow (up, down) will be visible at same time, or only one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is two way of doing that, depending on `datatables` version.

### EDIT for Datatables version 1.9 or less

You need to use [`fnHeaderCallback`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks). With this callback you can edit every `th` element in table header.

I have create a working example for you. 
LIVE : <strike>http://live.datatables.net/oduzov</strike>
CODE : <strike>http://live.datatables.net/oduzov/edit#javascript,html</strike>

Here is code behind that (open snippet to see the code) :

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "fnHeaderCallback": function(nHead, aData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
      // do this only once
      if ($(nHead).children("th").children("button").length === 0) {
        
        // button asc, but you can put img or something else insted
        var ascButton = $(document.createElement("button"))
          .text("asc");
        var descButton = $(document.createElement("button"))
          .text("desc"); // 

        ascButton.click(function(event) {
          var thElement = $(this).parent("th"); // parent TH element
          var columnIndex = thElement.parent().children("th").index(thElement); // index of parent TH element in header

          table.fnSort([
            [columnIndex, 'asc']
          ]); // sort call

          return false;
        });

        descButton.click(function(event) {
          var thElement = $(this).parent("th");
          var columnIndex = thElement.parent().children("th").index(thElement);

          table.fnSort([
            [columnIndex, 'desc']
          ]);

          return false;
        });

        $(nHead).children("th").append(ascButton, descButton);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### For Datatables version 1.10 and newer

callback have a new name, it's just [`headerCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/headerCallback). Everything else is the same, so use new callback insted of legacy api.