# Checkbox sort in DataTables using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, checkbox, datatable

I've been trying to sort a checkbox field in [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) jQuery plugin to check and uncheck.

I'm creating the input (checkbox) inside the table like this:

```
'<input type="checkbox" '+ check +' />'
```

check is containing the text "checked" or "".

So far I tried just to add DOM checkbox type of sort, like this:

```
{ "sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox" }
```

When I use the entire code from the plugin's [API documentation](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html), I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'afnSortData' of undefined
>   inside my console.

**Problem**: pressing on the column header won't sort the column by checked or unchecked checkboxes.

I would like to get suggestions how to fix the above mentioned error or another way to sort using only jQuery and plugin's methods.

Thanks.

---

#### EDIT

Just tried with a fixed code - no error. But sorting is messed up: it's just replacing with each other but not sorting. For example: if I have 1 checkbox checked and 9 not, the checked checkbox is switching from the third place to the sixth and again to the third and so on.

Comment: see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206894/column-sorting-in-jquery-datatables

Comment: no reference to checkbox sorting there.

Comment: it shows you how to sort on any type of input... you just need to reference the right properties, like the (input).checked property.

Comment: like "sSortDataType": "dom-(input).checked"  ? cause it is not working for me

Comment: go back to the link I provided... the (input) in my comment was just an placemark... in the link I provided they permorm a sort on different input types... jusr use that example, with checkbox properties...

Comment: not working or i just misunderstood you. can u write the entire code function please? @MaxOvrdrv

Comment: with little to no effort, i was able to find a direct example of what you want... on this very site we're on! Please make appropriate google searches before posting questions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912957/jquery-tablesorter-sort-by-column-having-input-elements

Comment: ok so next time you say it just be sure about the question. im NOT using jquery tableSorter, plus i tried to use click function with jquery but wheni create a dynamic input its not recognized as input at all when i try to contact it.

Comment: I went online, got a jQuery datatable (as stated in your question), then implemented the sort from previous link. Works perfect. in any case, I hope you find a solution. All the best!

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html this thing just worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

what I did create a bool var in hidden P so it will be in the same place as the checkbox. Then I disabled the option of change value in checkbox and the sorting is now working.

Comment: i have a similar situation, my problem is that when i sort the checkbox, the control is not going to the function defined for it ,i have a function named dom-checkbox defined, and the sSortDataType is dom-checbox, can u help ?

Comment: Plz can you provide the code snippet, as i am also facing same issue

Comment: @SachinGaikwad `<td><input type='checkbox' class='minimal' "+product_enabled+"><p style='visibility: hidden; display: none;'>"+products[i].enabled+"</p></td>`

Answer (score 5):

I had to slightly tweak the answer provided by `Moby's Stunt Double`. No additional sorting plug-in required! Just a little custom coding.

Thanks for all the ideas, everyone! For some reason I had to do special handling for my table that was not a general solution. Which was fine by me.

My checkbox was disabled and checked programatically, so I couldn't call `.checked`. The call based on iColumn also threw things off; probably because I had a hidden 0th column.

This is what worked for me:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( oSettings, iColumn ) {
    var aData = [];
    $(oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings)).each( function () {
        var checker = $(this).find('.classOnSurroundingSpan input');
        aData.push( checker.prop("checked")==true ? "1" : "0" );
    } );
    return aData;
}
```

My mark-up looked like this (the surrounding span was part of a solution to enable tracking [a click on a disabled checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6781467/469643)):

```
<span class='classOnSurroundingSpan'><input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled'/></span>
```

My table definition was (in part):

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    {"sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox",
    "aTargets":[1],
    "asSorting": ["desc"]}
]
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me so I wrote up a blog post on it.

http://blog.josephmisiti.com/sorting-booleans-in-jquery-datatables

Answer (score 3):

Found this example:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( oSettings, iColumn )
{
    var aData = [];
    $( 'td:eq('+iColumn+') input', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings) ).each( function () {
        aData.push( this.checked==true ? "1" : "0" );
    } );
    return aData;
}
```

Initialized like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Here: http://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

Comment: i wrote that this example gets an error and i wrote what kind of error it is in m question.

Comment: Do you have a thead tag and th tags for your headers by chance? I had issues once with DataTables and a poorly marked up table.

Comment: th tags inside thead tags @Moby's Stunt Double

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Table').DataTable({
        "language": datatableLanguaje,
        "aoColumnDefs": [ 
            { "aTargets": [8], "orderDataType": "dom-text", type:'string' },
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: 'string' },
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this example:

```
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function (settings, col) {
    return this.api().column(col, { order: 'index' }).nodes().map(function (td, i) {
        return $('input', td)[1].checked ? '1' : '0';
    });
}
```

Initialized like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
                        {
            "targets": 10,
                            "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox"
                        });
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some sort of unique identifier on the checkbox element, you can do something pretty clean like this example below (note this is a datatables [sorting plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/) syntax)

If your inputs look like:

```
<input data-app-id="1" class="migrateCheck" type="checkbox">
```

The plugin would look like:

```
function checkboxCompare(a, b) {
    var aId = $(a).data('app-id'),
        bId = $(b).data('app-id'),
        aChecked = $('.migrateCheck[data-app-id=' + aId + ']:checked').length,
        bChecked = $('.migrateCheck[data-app-id=' + bId + ']:checked').length;

    if (aChecked && !bChecked) return -1;
    else if (!aChecked && bChecked) return 1;

    return 0;
}

jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "checkbox-pre": function (a) {
        return a;
    },

    "checkbox-asc": function (a, b) {
        return checkboxCompare(a, b);
    },

    "checkbox-desc": function (a, b) {
        return checkboxCompare(b, a);
    }
});
```

Then simply specify `sType: "checkbox"` on the `aoColumnDefs` attr for the col that contains the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be sorted on by some simple html.

```
$('#table input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).prop('checked');
    var ele = $('<span>' + text + '</span>').hide();
    $(this).after(ele);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This stumped me for a bit.

I used the standard Plugin Code https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/custom-data-source/dom-checkbox:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('input', td).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
    } );
};
```

You need to specify "dom-checkbox" column types are sortable:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ "action" ] },
        { "sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox", "aTargets": [ "enabled" ] }
    ],
    "aaSorting": [
        [ 3, "desc" ]
    ]
});
```

In the view I enable the CheckBox columns to put the checkbox in (not tied to col number):

```
<th class="enabled">Enabled</th>
```